# "both" among commas

Tags: word-usage

I created this sentence intuitively and now wonder whether it is proper use of "both".

> Since these shows are gaining a lot of popularity, many arguments, both for and against this kind of entertainment, have been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the use of the commas. They serve to indicate nonrestrictive information in the sentence.

---

The sentence, without the information, would still make sense:

> Since these shows are gaining a lot of popularity, many arguments<s>, both for and against this kind of entertainment,</s> have been made.

The commas serve the same purpose as would a pair of actual parentheses:

> Since these shows are gaining a lot of popularity, many arguments (both for and against this kind of entertainment) have been made.

---

If you added *both* because you used commas, you were correct to do so. Without the commas, the use of *both* is awkward, and it's better to remove it:

> Since these shows are gaining a lot of popularity, many arguments for and against this kind of entertainment have been made.